# Visual Editor not working when Jetpack plugin is active

Tags: visual-editor, plugin-jetpack

After installing the Jetpack plugin, the visual editor stopped working.  The Visual tab is still there but the editor area is empty and the toolbar is missing.

I have deactivated all other plugins and the problem is still present.  (The only other one was Restricted Site Access).  Disabling Jetpack (or disconnecting it from Wordpress.com) fixes the problem, but I would like to use some functionality from Jetpack.

Has anyone else seen this problem, and is there a fix?  Is it a particular Jetpack configuration that causes this? I saw several [complaints](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-jetpack-by-wordpresscom-visual-editor-does-not-work-after-activating-jetpack) online, but not fixes.

Comment: I had the same problem and it's the short code module that causes the problem...
I'll contact the jetpack support to see how they can deal with it. Hope this will help someone else as well ! Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem using Jetpack v3.3 on http://ataxproforyou.com. I deactivated the whole jetpack plugin and the features came back, reactivated the plugin and was fine, until I connected it to my wordpress site http://ataxproforyou.wordpress.com and they went away again. I deactivated spell-check setting but that didn't resolve. I deactivated the Shortcode Embed feature and then it was functioning again.

FYI - this still causes problems in future releases but try deactivating the shortcode embed feature and that should resolve the problem.

Comment: Does the issue return if you reenable the Shortcode module?

Comment: Haven't tried...don't use the shortcode feature. And if it ain't broke....

Answer (score 0):

Finally this was solved by disabling some Jetpack modules.  I am not sure which one did it, but I suspect the spell checker.

To disable a Jetpack module, go to the Jetpack page on the dashboard, then click "Learn More" on a module.  The "Configure" button changes to "Deactivate", so now you can disable the module.  (This seems a bit counterintuitive and difficult to find.)

I hope this will help someone else too, as I noticed several people were complaining about the problems on various forums.

Answer (score -1):

go to wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules
disable Shortcode Embeds model 
this will work

Comment: Please try to add a bit more to this answer.